# How to animate images inside a specific element and make them stack at the bottom on animation end

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I have the following html:

```
<div class="inhaler__animation__container">
                <div class="inhaler__image__wrapper">
                    <img src="img/inhaler.png" alt="Inhaler animation image" title="Inhaler animation image">
                    <div class="inhaler__image__dot__wrapper">
                        <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
                        <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
                        <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
                        <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
                        <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
                        <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
                        <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
                        <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
                        <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
                        <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
                        <img src="img/pdot.png" alt="purple dot - Inhaler animation image" title="purple dot - Inhaler animation image">
                        <img src="img/wdot.png" alt="white dot - Inhaler animation image" title="white dot - Inhaler animation image">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="startanimation">Start animation</button>
                <button id="endanimation">Stop animation</button>
            </div>
```

I have one main image inhaler.png and the the remaining images wrapped inside `.inhaler__image__dot__wrapper` , now on click of the button i want the dots to animate inside the grey area of the main image and on click of the stop animation button , i want the dots to settle down at the bottom(with a trasition ofcourse, not just snap to the bottom) , but i believe with images this would be very hard.

- How would i restrict the dots to only inside the grey area, i believe this is impossible
- How would i make the images transition back to the bottom and stack up one over the other when the animation is stopped ?

I have created a small demo [here](http://peckingatcode.net/Animation-inhaler/).

Ofcourse in the beginning I.E. before the animation starts and at the end I.E. after the animation ends , the dots should be stacked at the bottom, how do i achieve this ?

So to summerise my questions ::-

- How do i restrict the dots inside the grey area ?
- How do i make the dots stack at the bottom ?

P.S. i am open to trying out a svg solution , if using an svg will solve the problem of restricting the dots to a given area. I have even created a svg [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/z3mwf12c/) .. not sure how i go about animating the dots in the svg and also not sure how i restrict the dots to the pink `rect` element , suggestions are welcome.

For a visual depiction see below images:

I want the dots to only animate inside the grey area.
[image]

The dots would be particles like below:

[image]

Comment: You'd need JS (perhaps `canvas`) for this...ideally some form of particle system.

Comment: @Paulie_D something like https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/ ?

Comment: Probably but I'm not familiar with it.